# Angular Material col-md not working with IE 10 < browser

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there any reasons why `layout-md` or other `ms` `gt-md` so on ... not working with IE 10 < ?

Comment: *Angular Material is targeted for all browsers with versions n-1; where n is the current browser version.* well, IE10 should have no problem. For AngularJS 1.3.x, IE8 or below is not supported. From AngularJS docs, *AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.*

Comment: @Raptor Please check out their doc site with IE10 https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/options First example `Layout responsieve` will not work when you resize the browser for mobile view in fact it should be column view. However it works fine with other browser